# Solve conflicts before commit in Git

Tags: git

I'm coming from SVN to Git. In SVN when two developers change the same file at same time (from the same file version), the last committer will get a conflict flag to solve before commit his changes. In Git the common way is the last commiter/pusher will solve the conflicts and generate a 3th commit and then push the original and merge commits.

Is possible merge the server changes before make a local commit and then make a single commit (without conflicts) in SVN style? To simplify assume both developers are using local copies of master instead others branches.

I'm aware it's a duplicated topic but most don't get the point.

Answer (score 5):

If you `git pull --rebase`, then you can resolve conflicts and make only a single commit with your new changes.  You won't have both your original commit and a merge: only an updated commit that resolves conflicts and includes all your new code.

Comment: Heh; didn't know that option existed. But yes, I was going to say that I like to do a git pull, rebase locally, and then push.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The second committer can pull the changes and merge them in as part of his original commit, but there is no real point in doing so. You can redo the changes that went into any commit in git. In fact using cherry picking you can merge and split commits as you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Git Solve conflicts:
Save file of other branch:

```
$ git checkout --theirs /path/to/file_with_conflicts
```

Save file of current branch:

```
$ git checkout --ours /path/to/file
```

## Remember commit changes